# Confidence interval for spline

Tags: spline, gam, cox-regression, cubic-spline

I am learning about spline variables for logit/Cox model and I generally notice that the confidence bands are narrow when odds/hazard ratio nears 1.  What is the possible reason for this?

Attaching a sample chart for reference.
[image]

Edit:  The code used to generate the above graph is based on a conditional logit model.

```
proc phreg data=have;
effect v1Spline=spline(v1/naturalcubic basis=tpf(noint) knotmethod=percentilelist(5 25 50 75 95);
model time*outcome(0)=v1Spline;
strata id;
run;
```

Comment: This figure does not show that the confidence bands are narrower when the hazard ratio nears 1. If you look at the far left of the figure, the series is approaching a hazard ratio of 1 and yet the bounds are larger than anywhere else in the figure. The simple answer will also be that there is more data where the bounds are smaller.

Comment: Can you give some more info on *how* you fitted this model (what package/code)? It looks like a sum-to-zero identifiability constraint was imposed on the spline to allow for a constant term in the model (the intercept). With such a constraint, the spline must pass through 0 (on the linear predictor scale) at some point (around the middle of the covariate space). Typically, once could include the uncertainty in the constant term in the interval construction, which would remove the problem. However, without such detail on how you fitted this, the above is speculation...

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks for your comments.  I have added the code in my original post.  I am a beginner in spline functions and I would appreciate any inputs on how I should proceed.  Thanks again Gavin.